# Rules and Triggers on Materialized Views in Postgresql

Tags: rules, postgresql-9.3, materialized-views, postgresql-9.4

Materialized views are a very nice new feature in Postgresql since 9.3, but... I have NOT been able to add rules or triggers in anyway. I have not found any documentation saying that you CANNOT add triggers or rules to materialized views, but using PgAdminIII and plain SQL I got errors (respectively "rules on materialized views are not supported" and "xxx is not a table or a view").

My materialized views are basically multiple joins which allow me to have an "encoded" table joined with look-up tables to create a readable table (e.g. a list of city postal codes whose code joins with the city name and population).
I need a trigger or rule to be able to update the original table when the materialized view is updated.

So my question is: is there a trick to add triggers or rules to materialized views?

Comment: Well the `create trigger` documentation lists the object types you can define a trigger on: "*table_name - The name (optionally schema-qualified) of the **table, view, or foreign table** the trigger is for*". Materialized views are not mentioned there. The same goes for `create rule`

Comment: Quite true, hopefully these will be implemented soon. I was hoping the documentation was not updated with new functionalities. Thanks.